# How do I serve website content based on IP address?

Tags: php, location, ip-address

I am building a website in which content will be different based on a user's geographical location. I would like to serve specific versions of the website based on the user's location, much like is done on the [Mutual of Omaha](https://www.mutualofomaha.com/life-insurance?src=homepage-card-links) website.

To me, the most logical way to do this is build different sections of the website for each geographic location. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Please, don't.  IP addresses are for routing network traffic, and do not reliably identify someone's location.  Additionally, you're creating a potential nightmare if you serve different content to clients at the same URL.  (At a minimum, read up on the `Vary` header, but know that it doesn't always work.)  Handle this client-side, with an option for people to enter their location if they choose to do so.  You can also use the geolocation API.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any code to get the location yet?

Comment: "Is there an easy way to do this?"  Do _what_ specifically?  Get someone's IP address?  Get a location based on the IP address?  Serve different content based on some met (or unmet) condition?  It is unclear what you're having trouble doing.

Comment: For ip geolocation you can use this API:

https://www.maxmind.com/en/open-source-data-and-api-for-ip-geolocation

You can get the user's country and then route the user to the appropriate content.